# Compiler looking for deleted constructor function in an argument when calling another function in C++

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, stepper, teensy

I am trying to control four different objects in a micro-controller (a sensor, a motor, a rotary encoder and a class in charge of the logic) with two functions that are mainly `switch state` statements, one that reads from the serial port and switches a variable accordingly, and one that reads from that variable and calls functions. I can call the functions from the individual objects directly in my `loop`, but when I call them with the function `serialTask();` the compiler fails. This are my headers:

This is `motor.h`. I used all those arguments in the constructor because I am using two libraries that use those elements to construct their own objects, `TMC2130Stepper`, `Stepper` and `StepControl`

```
 #pragma once

#include <TeensyStep.h>
#include <TMCStepper.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <pinout.h>

#define STALL_VALUE 15
#define R_SENSE 0.11 // Match to your driver
                      // SilentStepStick series use 0.11
                      // UltiMachine Einsy and Archim2 boards use 0.2
                      // Panucatt BSD2660 uses 0.1
                      // Watterott TMC5160 uses 0.075

                      //BOB = 0.3

struct Motor {

    public:

        Motor(const int dirPinArg, const int stepPinArg, const int enabPinArg, const int chipSelectArg, const int mosiSdiArg, const int misoSdoArg, const int clkArg, float rSenseArg);    

        int microsteps = 8;
        const uint32_t steps_per_mm = 80;
        int frameRatio = (200 * microsteps) / 2.55;
        int motorSpeed;
        bool motorState = false;
        bool isMoving = false;
        bool accelerated = false;

        void initializeDriver();
        void setupMotor();
        void accelerate();
        void moveMotor();
        void oneFrame();
        void oneFrameSlow();
        void moveMotorSlow();
        bool isAccelerated();
        void stepperTimer();
        void setSpeed();

        int spr = 16*200;  // 3200 steps per revolution

        TMC2130Stepper driver;
        Stepper motor;
        StepControl controller;

    private:


};
```

This is my encoder, `rotary.h`:

```
    /*
 * Rotary encoder library for Arduino.
 */
#pragma once

#ifndef rotary_h
#define rotary_h

#include "Arduino.h"

// Enable this to emit codes twice per step.
//#define HALF_STEP

// Enable weak pullups
#define ENABLE_PULLUPS

// Values returned by 'process'
// No complete step yet.
#define DIR_NONE 0x0
// Clockwise step.
#define DIR_CW 0x10
// Anti-clockwise step.
#define DIR_CCW 0x20

class Rotary
{
  public:
    Rotary(char, char);
    //Extra
    int encoderTest();
    // Process pin(s)
    unsigned char process();
    volatile int aState;
    volatile int aLastState;
    int counterNew;
    int counterOld;
  private:
    unsigned char state;
    unsigned char pin1;
    unsigned char pin2;

};

#endif
```

This is my `sensor.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <pinout.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <open-celluloid.h>
#include <Rotary.h>

struct Sensor {

    public:
            Sensor(int sensorPinArg);
            int readSensor(); 
            void calibrateSensor(OpenCelluloid openCelluloidArg, Rotary rotaryArg);
            void printSensorValues();  


            int sensorHigh{};
            int sensorLow{};
};
```

And this is the other class, `open-celluloid.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <Stream.h>
#include <Rotary.h>
#include <pinout.h>



class OpenCelluloid {

    public:

        OpenCelluloid();
        void stepperTimer();
        void homing();
        void checkTrigger();
        void calibrateShutter(Rotary rotaryArg);
        //HardwareSerial *serial;
        //HardwareSerial &serial1 = Serial;
        //TimerOne *timer1;

        const int sensorThreshold = 300;
        int lastSensorState = 0;
        uint8_t sensorState = 0; //
        uint8_t stepState = 0; //


        //trigger
        volatile bool gateOpen{};
        volatile bool trigger{};
        volatile uint8_t triggerCounter{};
        volatile bool sameState = true;
        volatile byte threshold[8];
        volatile uint8_t sum_threshold{};
        volatile uint8_t gate{};
        volatile uint8_t gatePrevious{};
        volatile uint8_t shutterCounter{};
        volatile bool boolGate{};
        //volatile bool boolState = !digitalRead(sensor);
        volatile bool boolState{};
        volatile bool home_position{};      
        volatile bool startCapture;

        uint8_t doFullRotation{};
        int stepCount = 10000;
        volatile char state;

        //Rotary rotary = Rotary(5, 6);



    private:

        Stream *_streamRef;
        TimerOne *_timerRef;
        //Stepper *_motorRef;
        //StepControl *_controllerRef;

};
```

Apart from that, I have another .h file in which I have functions:

```
    #pragma once

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TMCStepper.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <Stream.h>
#include "TeensyStep.h"
#include <Rotary.h>
#include <open-celluloid.h>
#include <pinout.h>
#include <motor.h>
#include <sensor.h>


#define auto_reset              20
#define start_moving_forward    21
#define start_moving_backward   22
#define keep_moving             23
#define stoping                 24
#define auto_end                25
#define one_frame               26
#define hundred_frames          27
#define loading                 28
#define keep_moving_slow        29
#define test                    30
#define test_digital            31
#define test_analog             32
#define encoder_test            33
#define calibrate_shutter       34
#define calibrate_sensor        35
#define read_sensor             36
#define print_values            37
#define test_acceleration       38

void readSensor();
void oneFrame();
void oneFrameSlow();
void serialTask(Sensor sensorArg, Rotary rotaryArg, OpenCelluloid openCelluloidArg, Motor motorArg);
void stateSwitch(OpenCelluloid openCelluloidArg);
void encoder();
void calibrateShutter();
void testDigital(int button);
void testAnalog(int pin);
```

The problem is the function `serialTask();` which looks like this in the file `functions.cpp`:

```
void serialTask(OpenCelluloid openCelluloidArg, Motor motorArg, Sensor sensorArg, Rotary rotaryArg) {
  switch (openCelluloidArg.state) {
    case auto_reset:
      openCelluloidArg.state = auto_end;
      break;

    case start_moving_forward:
      if (!motorArg.isMoving) {
        //homing();
        //accelerate();
        motorArg.isMoving = true;
      } else {
        openCelluloidArg.state = keep_moving;
        motorArg.isMoving = true;
      }
      digitalWrite(dir_Pin, LOW);
      //delayMicroseconds(10000);
      openCelluloidArg.startCapture = true;
      break;

    case start_moving_backward:
      if ( !motorArg.isMoving) {
        //homing();
        motorArg.isMoving = true;
      } else {
        openCelluloidArg.state = keep_moving;
        motorArg.isMoving = true;
      }
      digitalWrite(dir_Pin, HIGH);
      //delayMicroseconds(10000);
      openCelluloidArg.startCapture = true;

      break;

    case keep_moving:
      openCelluloidArg.home_position = false;
      motorArg.moveMotor();
      //moveMotorPwm();
      //serialFrames();
      openCelluloidArg.state = keep_moving;
      break;

    case keep_moving_slow:
      openCelluloidArg.home_position = false;
      //moveMotorSlow();
      openCelluloidArg.state = keep_moving_slow;
      break;

    case stoping:
      digitalWrite(step_Pin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(enabPin, HIGH);
      openCelluloidArg.state = auto_end;
      motorArg.isMoving = false;
      digitalWrite(enabPin, LOW);
      openCelluloidArg.startCapture = false;
      break;

    case auto_end:
      openCelluloidArg.home_position = false;
      break;

    case one_frame:
      //oneFrame();
      motorArg.oneFrameSlow();
      openCelluloidArg.state = auto_end;
      break;

    case loading:
      if ( !motorArg.isMoving) {
        motorArg.isMoving = true;
      } else {
        openCelluloidArg.state = keep_moving_slow;
        motorArg.isMoving = true;
      }
      digitalWrite(dir_Pin, LOW);
      break;


    case test:
      sensorArg.readSensor();
      break;

    case test_digital:
      testDigital(encoButton);
      break;

    case test_analog:
      testAnalog(encoButton);
      break; 

    case encoder_test:
      rotaryArg.encoderTest();
      break;    

    case calibrate_shutter:
      openCelluloidArg.calibrateShutter(rotaryArg);
      break;

    case calibrate_sensor:
      sensorArg.calibrateSensor(openCelluloidArg, rotaryArg);
      break;

    case read_sensor:
      sensorArg.readSensor();
      break;

    case print_values:
      sensorArg.printSensorValues();
      break;

    case test_acceleration:
      motorArg.accelerate();
   }
};
```

Whenever I call this function in the main `loop()`, the compiler tells me `use of deleted function 'Motor::Motor(const Motor&)'`. This is how my `main.cpp` file looks like:

```
    #include <Arduino.h>
#include <open-celluloid.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <TeensyStep.h>
#include <TMCStepper.h>
#include <functions.h>
#include <motor.h>
#include <Rotary.h>



Motor motorObj(dir_Pin, step_Pin, enabPin, chipSelect, mosiSdi, misoSdo, clk, 0.11f);
Rotary rotaryObj(channelA, channelB);
Sensor sensorObj(sensor);
OpenCelluloid openCelluloidObj{};
void setup() {


pinMode(enabPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(step_Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dir_Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
pinMode(channelA, INPUT);
pinMode(channelB, INPUT);
pinMode(startStop, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dirSwitch, OUTPUT);
pinMode(encoButton, INPUT);
pinMode(misoSdo, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(mosiSdi, OUTPUT);
pinMode(clk, OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(enabPin, LOW);
digitalWrite(dir_Pin, LOW);
digitalWrite(step_Pin, LOW);
digitalWrite(chipSelect, LOW);
digitalWrite(mosiSdi, LOW);
digitalWrite(clk, LOW);

Serial.begin(115200);
motorObj.setupMotor();
openCelluloidObj.startCapture = false;
digitalWrite(step_Pin, motorObj.motorState);
rotaryObj.aLastState = digitalRead(channelA);
openCelluloidObj.state = auto_end;



};

void loop() {

  stateSwitch(openCelluloidObj);
  serialTask(sensorObj, rotaryObj, openCelluloidObj, motorObj);
};
```

Also I have another .h file called `pinout.h` in which all my pins are defined as constants and gets called from the other files, but that doesn't seem to be important. The compiler also sends me to errors deep within the libraries that I am using for the motor, but that only happens when I call `serialTask()`. Maybe there is a problem of redefinition, I am really lost here, any help is greatly appreciated. This are the other error messages that I get:

```
StepControlBase<a, t>::StepControlBase(const StepControlBase<a, t>&) [with Accelerator = LinStepAccelerator; TimerField = TimerField]' is protected

use of deleted function 'StepControlBase<a, t>::StepControlBase(const StepControlBase<a, t>&) [with Accelerator = LinStepAccelerator; TimerField = TimerField]'
```

Comment: Is all of this code needed? You should reduce the code to [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your argument is taking Motor by value, so it needs to do a copy.

The copy constructor is deleted when you create your own constructor.

Try passing by reference (`const Motor&` or `Motor&`).

Comment: thank you for your answer. What I understand is that I should define my function as `void serialTask(OpenCelluloid openCelluloidArg, Motor &motorArg, Sensor sensorArg, Rotary rotaryArg)`, is that correct?